# how to evaluate $\left[f(x) e^{-i \omega x}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ with $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

$\left[f(x) e^{-i \omega x}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ with  $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=0$.

$\left[f(x) e^{-i \omega x}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\left[f(x) (\cos (\omega x)+i \sin(\omega x)) \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}=?$

$\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}\cos ((\omega x)+i \sin(\omega x))$ does not exist because $\sin,\cos$ are oscillating functions.

Comment: Hint: $\vert e^{-i\omega x}f(x)\vert = \vert f(x)\vert\to 0$.